# How to add a third javascript else if statement to a button?

Tags: javascript, function

EDIT
I meant to say, how could I add a third else if statement that would fire on the third click.

basically it opens and hide a different element on the first, second and third click.

so I want to add one more function to make a total of 3 functions to this onclick event that changes depending on how many times you click on the button. I am just not sure how to add a third function.

```
        <div class="base" id="base">
        <img src="img/base.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="base one" id="one">
        <img src="img/one.svg">
    </div>


    <div class="base two" id="two">
        <img src="img/two.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="base three" id="three">
        <img src="img/three.svg">
    </div>
    <button class="test" id="test">btn</button>




var action = 1;
test.onclick = function viewSomething() {
if (action == 1) {
    base.style.display = "none";
    one.style.display = "block";
    action = 2;
    console.log(tets)
} else {
    one.style.display = "none";
    two.style.display = "block";
    action = 1;
}
```

}

Comment: `if .. else if .. else`

Comment: You basically already have everything you need, you just have to make use of it: `if (action === 1) { ... action = 2; } else if(action === 2) { ... action = 3; } else if (action === 3) { ... }` and so on.

Comment: @FelixKling This actually worked. I've been up all night working on this project, that I failed to see that the answer was right in front of me. thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the basic setup, you just need to extend it:

```
var action = 1;
test.onclick = function viewSomething() {
if (action == 1) {
    base.style.display = "none";
    one.style.display = "block";
    action = 2;
    console.log(tets)
} else if (action === 2) {
   // ...
   action = 3;
} else if (action === 3) {
    one.style.display = "none";
    two.style.display = "block";
    action = 1;
}
```

Having said that, if you always go sequentially from one "action" to the other, you could consider moving each "action" into a separate function, storing all those functions into an array and have the click handler simply advance the index:

```
const actions = [
  function(event) {
    base.style.display = "none";
    one.style.display = "block";
  },
  function(event) {
    one.style.display = "none";
    two.style.display = "block";
  },
  function(event) {
    // ...
  },
];

let actionIndex = 0;
test.onclick = function viewSomething(event) {
  actions[actionIndex](event);
  actionIndex = (actionIndex + 1) % actions.length;
};
```

The advantage of the solution is that you are decoupling the action "control" from the actions themselves and that you can more easily add and rearrange additional actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a *third function* since I can only see `viewSomething`, but you can add an `if else` block to your `if` statement:

```
if (action == 1) {
    base.style.display = "none";
    one.style.display = "block";
    action = 2;
    console.log(tets)
} else if (this == that) {
    // your logic here
} else {
    one.style.display = "none";
    two.style.display = "block";
    action = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want three different functions (you currently have one function and two if statements), you need to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
function clickOne() {
  console.log("first!");
}
function clickTwo() {
  console.log("second!");
}
function clickThree() {
  console.log("third!");
}
var test = document.querySelector("#test");
test.addEventListener("click", clickOne);
setTimeout(() => {
  test.addEventListener("click", clickTwo);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
  test.addEventListener("click", clickThree);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<button class="test" id="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: I apologize, I'm honestly really tired from finals... hahaha. I meant to say, how could I add a third else if statement that would fire on the third click. @Rojo

Comment: @cresenmoon [half of a glazier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67196109/10210841) has that for you and so does [Flex Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67197573/10210841).